# I'm using Viewpager fragment and want to use "ShareActionProvider" on its Nested Fragment..! Is it possible?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-nested-fragment, shareactionprovider

there is Viewpager used in my code in which 4 Fragments. when I click on Any Fragment Item it will redirect to another fragment class in which I want Share Action to be used..

But it didn't Support..

@Override

```
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    menu.clear();
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu1, menu);


}



/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.support.v4.app.Fragment#onOptionsItemSelected(android.view.MenuItem)
 */
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.menu_item_share:
         /* mShareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) item.getActionProvider();  
          setShareIntent(createShareIntent());
          return true;  */
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Success", 100).show();
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

I used Above code in my Fragment class..! In which I mention setHasOptionsMenu(true); in OncreatView() Methos.. // But Didn't get Solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Done with this Solution..

ShareActionProvider mShareActionProvider = new ShareActionProvider(getActivity());
    if(mShareActionProvider != null) {
        mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(createShareIntent());
    } else {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Share action provider is null");
    }
```